# Custom Generator interlock switch

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, generator

I have just wired a 8KW backup generator into my Siemens main load center.
I used the top right-hand bus position for the 50A breaker to the generator.  All of the interlock switches for Siemens panels are designed for a 1-3/8 in. spacing between the top of the breaker slot and the bottom of the main cutoff slot. On my panel, the distance is going to be 2-3/8. I am capable of designing and building a custom interlock, but would much rather purchase one that is expandable and UL approved. Any ideas of where to find one?**

Comment: Expandable? What would that even *mean* for an interlock? As for UL Listing, you need that, and you do that by buying an interlock designed for your specific panel and using it as deigned. If no such interlock exists, you may need to put in a subpanel that does have one made for it, and move any loads you want on the generator to that subpanel.

Comment: The problem without having the expensive UL approval is it will not pass inspection and insurance can be cancelled/denied.  Maybe add a picture of your panel.

Comment: "Where to find one" is a Shopping Question and sorta offtopic here. "Does it exist, and what's the alternative" would be a better fit.  Subpanel's a good idea anyway, to separate the circuits you want backed up from those you don't so you don't have to throw all those breakers manually to reduce load before running with the generator.

Comment: In addition to a picture, model # of panel would help.

Comment: Many people start google searching and find 3rd party makers of interlocks, and assume that's all there is. **Have you talked to Siemens?** Siemens makes at least 11 different interlocks for their panels, and they are OEM - can't get better than that.  In fact many 3rd party sites simply sell the Siemens units rather than make their own.

Answer (score 4):

### Talk to Siemens themselves

Siemens is very serious about supporting their panels with generator interlocks. They make *at least* 11 models of which we are aware (ECSBPK01 through 11).

Siemens only recently started using Siemens branding on their Murray panels, so most likely if yours self-identifies as a Siemens, it'll have an interlock *from Siemens* that fits.

When you say

> All of the interlock switches for Siemens panels are designed for a 1-3/8 in.

what you mean is that you've done a web search for interlocks and found third-party sites which sell interlocks for legacy panels.  Those are the ones specifying spacing like that.  The web search only brings you up sites who are actively doing SEO to market on search engines" - which is not the manufacturer, obviously (they have an authorized dealer network they sell through).  Typically these 3rd party sites are well aware of the OEM interlocks, and rather than custom engineer a direct competitor, they simply sell you the OEM interlock at twice the price. However they don't bother to sell or stock every interlock in the OEM line, or they may remove it from their site when they are out of stock.

Comment: Harper, you were right, I did web search for generator interlock kit for my panel, MC2040B-1200RJBC, and found lots of kits, but none that looked like it would fit.  So, I called Siemens CS and they eventually came up with kit ECSBPK09  which is supposed to fit.  I found one and ordered it. I will be a little surprised if it fits, but when it does, I will answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

1" = 1 single breaker. So just move the breaker that is in the way down and the generator double breaker up. Done.

While there is general advice in many areas for breaker location (e.g., surge protector near the main breaker, solar at the far end, etc.), a generator interlock is one of the few (possibly "only") situations where physical position of a breaker really, really, really matters.

Is it possible to design your own interlock? Yes. Is it possibly you can convince the inspector that it is good enough? Yes. But why bother when there is a super simple solution with no downside.

If the existing top breaker (the one that needs to be moved) doesn't have any slack in the wire (only need 2" more than it has right now) then splice in an extension. That can't be too hard since single breakers are 120V and it is extremely rare to find a 120V circuit > 30A, so standard wire nuts will work just fine. And if the problem is moving the 50A breaker up, that can't be too hard either.

Comment: It seems OP's problem is the space/distance is larger than standard(unknown if OP is measuring wrong or has a weird panel).  OP says the breaker is in topmost place.

Comment: @crip659 You're right. But it just doesn't add up. Either OP is finding interlocks for the wrong panel (and needs to find the right one) or does have a breaker in the way. Until we see a picture that explains it (or contradicts it), I'm sticking with my answer.

Comment: I thought OP said there was space listed as 'accessory' between the main and first breaker, when I first read the question, but it is not in the question now.

Comment: Design your own interlock? Sure. Convince the inspector to pass it? Maybe. Convince the insurance company that it's not the fault when the house burns down? Don't bet on it.

Comment: I guess I am OP.  I appreciate your comments, and took Harper's advice and called Siemens and maybe have a solution. But, addressing each point, I think I have a weird panel. Yes, I need the right interlock (ECSBPK09).   I have a picture - just don't know how to upload it on this forum so you can see it. If you could, you'd see the spot labeled "accessory", but there is no bus behind it.  I'm going to hold off on fabricating my own interlock for reasons given, at least until I try the on-order ECSBPK09 kit.  The panel, BTW, is a Siemens MC2040B-1200RJBC.